# Not able to spark-submit jar on Windows

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I'm really a newbie on Big Data area and just started learning about Apache Spark, my problem is that I'm not able to process an Java application in the standalone spark cluster. My project is maven compiled, into a jar, with the spark core dependency. The master and worker are being successfully created, but the spark-submit does nothing.

Here is the project main class:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                  .setAppName("Spark App");
          JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
          JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD = sparkContext.textFile("C:\\tmp\\nationalparks.csv");
          System.out.println("Number of lines in file = " + stringJavaRDD.count());

    }
}
```

Here is the master creation:

`spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`

The worker creation:

`spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://ip:port`

And the jar submit:

`spark-submit --master spark://ip:port --class App C:\...\spark-teste-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

All I got after doing this is:

```
20/01/20 23:17:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

And the spark monitor (http://localhost:8080/) displays the worker but no applications. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There are no errors in the execution, you can ignore the warning messages. Try to do some "action"s on the created RDD, such as stringJavaRDD .take(10).foreach(println)

Comment: Spark is lazy evaluated, you will not see any execution until you call any action on RDD